# How to record a trace with command line tool - record_android_trace for android

Tags: android, performance, systrace, perfetto

I need to trace system trace and view-analyse using Perfetto saw in this video [Android app performance with Perfetto, record_android_trace](https://youtu.be/YEX26m89fco?t=1753) where it is mentioned that the tool - [Recording a trace with command line](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing#recording-a-trace)  is downloaded and made into an executable, Can anyone help me some other resources to successfully set up this.

Answer (score 0):

The best source of documentation is the [Perfetto website](https://perfetto.dev). It's difficult to give any more advice without knowing more about the specific problems you are running into.

Comment: yaa, Actually We just needed to download the script file, run the command from the correct directory  in terminal